# Edit File During it is processing in Unity

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, file-handling, editing

I am making a unity app in which it read data from a text file and
take actions accordingly and I want to update this file after regular intervals.
When I tried to update my file it says file is in process you can't edit it.

I have also tried .xml file extension for editing it but it didn't work

Which file format can be edited during processing?

Comment: You said you Tried Can you provide  the way you tried.

Answer (score 0):

We we can’t help without code. But Unity can process any file format like .txt .xml etc but you need to give read/write permission and also you need to check, is the process done before writing the file. This is the whole how read/write works in any platforms. I hope you get idea.

Comment: I am making app for my Final Year project I hear from someone that there is a special file format in which you can edit the file while it is being used by any software if you have any idea about it then please tell me.

Comment: I have no idea about that if there are any files like that. And by the way what do you mean by “being used by any software” because as far as I know processor can only start processing once previous processes done.